# Mocking node modules with Jest and @std/esm

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm currently having an issue writing tests for a node application that uses `@std/esm`. I've setup a manual mock of a node module inside a `__mocks__` directory and the following code shows a test for the file uses this mocked node module. (It's used in db.mjs)

```
const loader = require('@std/esm')(module, { cjs: true, esm: 'js' })
const Db = loader('../src/db').default

const db = new Db()

describe('getNotes', () => {
  it('gets mocked note', () => {
    db.getNote()
  })
})
```

However, when I run Jest, my manual mock is not being used, it is using the real node module.

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Jest is particular about the location of your mocks. From their documentation on [mocking node modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules):

> For example, to mock a scoped module called @scope/project-name,
>   create a file at **mocks**/@scope/project-name.js, creating the
>   @scope/ directory accordingly.

In your case it would be `__mocks__/@std/esm.js`